# MAM: What is the purpose of the nonce in the masked_payload?

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging, nonce

I am researching how Masked Authenticated Messaging (MAM) works.
The masked_payload is created in the create function in file: https://github.com/iotaledger/MAM/blob/master/mam/src/mam.rs

masked_payload = 
[
  Encoded 
  Index,
  Encoded Message Length,
  encrypted 
  [
    Message,
    Nonce,
    Signature,
    Encoded Number of Siblings,
    Siblings
  ]
]

My question is what is the purpose of this Nonce in the masked_payload?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the nonce is explained in:
https://www.mobilefish.com/download/iota/masked_payload_part20.pdf

Answer (score 1):

On the IOTA blog they state:

> an additional nonce may be used as a revocable encryption key

If I understand it correctly (and I believe I saw this in a MAM POC somewhere), it can be used to withdraw access to a specific subscriber of a restricted MAM stream. However, I struggle to understand how this works.

source: https://blog.iota.org/introducing-masked-authenticated-messaging-e55c1822d50e